# Is 'google Kubernetes standard disks' quickly enough for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating a Cassandra cluster in Google Cloud Platform in Kubernetes.

I saw that google provides different type of disks, the question is: "Is 'google Kubernetes standard disks' quickly enough for Cassandra?", or I should to change to SSD disks?

I think that the best solution is Local SSD disks, but I don't know if is an overkill.

Anyone have experience with this?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/

[image]

[image]

Comment: depends on what your doing and your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to cassandra's [documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/hardware.html), they recommend

> local ephemeral SSDs

Though, you won't notice significant performance degradation running on regional/zonal SSD's.

It is more important to allocate  **commitlogs** (`commitlog_directory`) and **data dictionary** (`data_file_directories`) to the separate physical drives.